# Why can't Adobe Acrobat finish printing to a pdf file?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf

I have Adobe Acrobat 9, Windows 7.

This has been happening a lot lately. When I print a pdf document to a pdf file using Adobe Acrobat, it stops after a few pages, without completing the document. The dialog that says printing... stays open and the progress bar keeps advancing. But Windows gives me a pop up that says that the printing is complete, and when I open the printed pdf file, it is incomplete. I have no idea why this is happening.

Anyone has had a similar issue? Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes acrobat is not able to process the particular page you are trying to print

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-print-pdf-image.html

Comment: But this happens with ALL pdf files I try to print!

Answer (score 0):

(if on windows) try clicking; start > devices and printers > right click on Adobe PDF and select printing preferences, then uncheck the box which says "rely on system fonts only; do not use document fonts"